# ssh key authentication - port other than 22 involved

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys

I've noted this entry in `auth.log`

> Accepted publickey for myuser from *`ip_address`* port 51150 ssh2

That entry corresponds with my ssh-key-based login event. SSH is listening to default port - 22.

What is the role of logged port 51150 and does it mean I cannot use restrictive iptables settings that blocks all traffic incoming to ports other than ones that I have previously specified (like 20,21,25,80,443,143...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port number shown is the ephemeral **client-side** port number, corresponding to the **source** port as seen by the SSH server.  Server-side, **all** ssh connections are to port 22.

Here's me `ssh`ing into my colo'ed server, and confirming the port listed in the relevant `syslog` file:

```
odessa% ssh www.teaparty.net
[...]
[me@lory ~]$ tail -2 /var/log/facility/authpriv 
Dec  9 12:36:26 lory sshd[16793]: Accepted publickey for me from 78.46.204.154 port 58212 ssh2
Dec  9 12:36:27 lory sshd[16793]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user me by (uid=0)
```

And here's the output from the **client** showing the connection:

```
odessa% netstat -an|grep 22|grep 58212
tcp        0      0 78.46.204.154:58212         178.18.123.145:22           ESTABLISHED
```

As you can see, the port number server-side is 22, as expected.  It is the **client**-side port number that is 58212.  Miloshio, since most `iptables` rules to permit access to services look something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

they are unaffected by the change in source-port number from client to client, as they only care about *destination* port number.  Only if you were to write a rule like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --sport 58212 -j ACCEPT
```

would it need changing for each new client - which is why you'd have to be insane to do that, and no-one does.

Comment: @BE77Y and MadHatter, accepted answers aren't self-deleteable, just like you can't delete a question once it has an upvoted answer.  Anyway, at BE77Y's request, I deleted his answer, so you may want to go ahead and edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow, that sounds **much** more logical, I should know that it's client-side port :D. Thanks MadHatter.

Comment: You're also Hetzner client :D cheers fellow

Comment: You're welcome.  And though I don't use them for my colo'ed box, I do tend to use them for other things - including the above jumping-off point.